# CALayer's height is not the same with displayed after rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

The `CALayer`'s `frame.size.height` property indicated its height after rotation-transformed. But what I see is not true:

```
CATransform3D perspective = CATransform3DIdentity;
perspective.m34 = -1.0 / 300;
grayContainer.layer.sublayerTransform = perspective;

blackHeightIndicator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2, 100)];
blackHeightIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[grayContainer addSubview:blackHeightIndicator];

redView = [[UIView alloc] init];
redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
redView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
redView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
[grayContainer addSubview:redView];

CGFloat ang = 0.3 * M_PI;

redView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(ang, 1, 0, 0);

CGRect f1 = blackHeightIndicator.frame;
f1.size.height = redView.layer.frame.size.height;
blackHeightIndicator.frame = f1;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Why? A demo project is available here: [Demo Project](http://landinggearup.com/download/Transform3DDiffTest.zip)

Thank you.

Comment: Please, add the code, that draws the height and the interior. BTW: You mean `….size.height`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it related to the [Graphical projection - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection)

what you see in simulator is perspective, the projection line are **not parallel**, they vanishing in a same point(which is the `m34` value you setting affect, and be different with different `m34` value)

but the value of frame you get is with a **parallel** projection line

you can see from the right side of the image below, notice in the 90 degree case is so obvious what I mean

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me what the IDE is you are using?

Comment: @AlbertZhang it's reveal